# how to insert Two List box items into two columns of same table of database c# window form

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I am trying to insert two listbox items in two columns of same table of a database .but i could not would you please help me.

Please find the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static string var = "";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-6056TSF;Initial Catalog=LibararyManagement;Integrated Security=True");
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Attribute where Test_Id like '"+Form2.a+"' ", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        var arr = new Label[dt.Rows.Count];

        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var lab = new Label();
            lab.Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            // Other properties sets for tbox
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(lab);
            arr[i] = lab;
            lab.Location = new Point(32, 32 + (i * 32));
            lab.Width = 62;
        }
        textbox();
    }

    void textbox()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Attribute Where Test_Id like '"+Form2.a+"' ", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        var arr = new TextBox[dt.Rows.Count];

        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var texbox = new TextBox();
            //teexbox.Text = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            // Other properties sets for tbox
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(texbox);
            arr[i] = texbox;
            texbox.Location = new Point(122,32 + (i * 32));
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TextBox text in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(text.Text);
        }


        foreach (Label lbl in panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(lbl.Text);
        }

        foreach (var b in listBox2.Items)
        {
            string msg = b.ToString();

            foreach (var a in listBox1.Items)
            {
                string message = a.ToString();
                con.Open();
                string saveStaff = "INSERT into Reg_Test_Atrribute(RTA_Name, RTA_Value , TR_Id ) " +
                   " VALUES ('" + message + "', '" + msg + "' ,'" + Form2.a + "');";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(saveStaff, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Saved");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working but if dt.row.counts = 4 the nested loop runs 16 time

Comment: Show the code you have so far

Comment: see answer..i am getting values from dynamic controls to two listboxes and used nested foreach loop

Comment: its working but if dt.row.counts = 4 nested lopp run 16 time..

Comment: You can [edit] your question to put your non-working code into it instead of  putting it in an answer.

Comment: done let me know whats problem in my code

Comment: congratulation to me ..i have made it.....but im sad whenever i asked question here never get an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace dyna
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public static string var = "";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-6056TSF;Initial Catalog=LibararyManagement;Integrated Security=True");
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();




                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Attribute where Test_Id like '"+Form2.a+"' ", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();


                var arr = new Label[dt.Rows.Count];

                for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var lab = new Label();


                        lab.Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();

                    // Other properties sets for tbox

                    this.panel1.Controls.Add(lab);

                    arr[i] = lab;
                    lab.Location = new Point(32, 32 + (i * 32));
                    lab.Width = 62;
                }

                textbox();
            }
            void textbox()
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Attribute Where Test_Id like '"+Form2.a+"' ", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                var arr = new TextBox[dt.Rows.Count];

                for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var texbox = new TextBox();


                    //teexbox.Text = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();

                    // Other properties sets for tbox

                    this.panel1.Controls.Add(texbox);

                    arr[i] = texbox;
                    texbox.Location = new Point(122,32 + (i * 32));

                }
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                foreach (TextBox text in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(text.Text);

                }


                foreach (Label lbl in panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(lbl.Text);


                }


                foreach (var b in listBox2.Items)
                {
                    string msg = b.ToString();


                foreach (var a in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    string message = a.ToString();


                    con.Open();
                    string saveStaff = "INSERT into Reg_Test_Atrribute(RTA_Name, RTA_Value , TR_Id ) " +
                           " VALUES ('" + message + "', '" + msg + "' ,'" + Form2.a + "');";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(saveStaff, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Saved");

                }
            }}
            private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

                }

            }






}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace dyna
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string var = "";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-6056TSF;Initial Catalog=LibararyManagement;Integrated Security=True");
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();




            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Attribute where Test_Id like '"+Form2.a+"' ", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();


            var arr = new Label[dt.Rows.Count];

            for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var lab = new Label();


                    lab.Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();

                // Other properties sets for tbox

                this.panel1.Controls.Add(lab);

                arr[i] = lab;
                lab.Location = new Point(32, 32 + (i * 32));
                lab.Width = 62;
            }

            textbox();
        }
        void textbox()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Attribute Where Test_Id like '"+Form2.a+"' ", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            var arr = new TextBox[dt.Rows.Count];

            for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var texbox = new TextBox();


                //teexbox.Text = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();

                // Other properties sets for tbox

                this.panel1.Controls.Add(texbox);

                arr[i] = texbox;
                texbox.Location = new Point(122,32 + (i * 32));

            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            foreach (TextBox text in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(text.Text);

            }


            foreach (Label lbl in panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(lbl.Text);


            }


            con.Open();
                String query = "INSERT INTO Reg_Test_Atrribute (RTA_Name,RTA_Value,TR_Id) VALUES(@RTA_Name,@RTA_Value,@TR_Id)";

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,con);
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RTA_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                foreach (var b in listBox2.Items)
                {

                    command.Parameters["@RTA_Name"].Value = b.ToString();
                }
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("RTA_Value", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TR_Id", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                foreach (var a in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    command.Parameters["RTA_Value"].Value = a.ToString();
                    command.Parameters["@TR_Id"].Value = Form2.a.ToString();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                con.Close();
                /*con.Open();
                string saveStaff = "INSERT into Reg_Test_Atrribute(RTA_Name, RTA_Value , TR_Id ) " +
                       " VALUES ('" + message + "', '" + msg + "' ,'" + Form2.a + "');";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(saveStaff, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Saved");
                */

            }
        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

            }

        }
```